# Libgdx android error getSlotFromBufferLocked

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing a game for android with libgdx.

Today, after I've updated my android device to android 6.0, I've noticed a strange error on the logcat when the game starts and ends:

level:    "**E**" , 
the tag:  "**Surface**" 
the text: "**getSlotFromBufferLocked**: unknown buffer:0xaed2a950

I've never seen this error before and appears also with previous versions of the app.
Now I'm trying to create a new game and see if this happens also with an "empty" game but first I want to know what this error is related to. I don't know if this is due to the new version of android.

Comment: I had the same error when resuming from a input dialog with Android 6 too

Comment: I' tried with a game ex-novo and the error appears... Next I'll try with a different device with a different android version, I'll post the result

Comment: I've tried with Android 4.4.2 and the error doesn't appear.
I believe that it started to appear with the new Android version but I haven't the proof.